# IF condition in view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Is it possible to have a if condition in VIEWS

eg

```sql
CREATE VIEW
as

  DECLARE @Count int
  SET @Count=-1
  select @Count=EmpID from EmployeeDetails where ID=200
  IF @Count=-1
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TEAM1
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TEAM1
  END
```

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your questions [as previously requested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816306/problem-in-my-ms-sql-query-it-taking-2-mins-to-perform). The `{}` icon on the toolbar allows you to format code. Why are both branches of the `IF` doing the same thing?

Comment: @Martin thanks  Martin i will do this next time

Comment: has any of the answers solved your problem? if so please mark it as the answer as it will help others who have the same problem as you in the future and google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No I don't believe this is possible.

You could use a stored procedure instead to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 16):

You could try something sneaky with a UNION :

```
SELECT {fieldlist}
FROM Table1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT EmpID FROM EmployeeDetails WHERE ID = 200)

UNION ALL

SELECT {fieldlist}
FROM Table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT EmpID FROM EmployeeDetails WHERE ID = 200)
```

This method would require both SELECT statements to return the same set of fields, although their sources might be different.

Comment: This also does the test for existence twice. I couldn't think of a way of avoiding that but suspect there might be a cunning way.

Comment: This must have common fields. But in my case first table has 10 columns and in second table only 2 columns

Comment: Then a view cannot be used as it must return the same set of fields.

Comment: thank you @CodeByMoonlight the UNION tip helped me with a similar problem.

Answer (score 10):

Views only allow select statements as stated in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

if you need to do if on column values you can use a

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN COLUMN1 = 1 THEN COLUMNX ELSE COLUMNY END
FROM TABLE1
```

if your need exceeds this you should create a select from a table valued function instead of a view.

What you need is a simple Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DOSOMETHING
(   
    @ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @ID > 100
        SELECT 1 AS ID,'ME' AS NAME, GETDATE() AS VARIABLEDATECOL, NEWID() AS VARIABLEGUID
    ELSE
        SELECT 2 AS ID, 'YOU' AS NAME
END
```

Answer (score -1):

simply use a udf (User defined Function)
Here you can use IF, ELSE, WHILE etc.

But when you are manipulating data (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) then you have to use Stored Procedures because udf's aren't able to do that