# Can I use complex in a view?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a view from table **T1** with two fields, one is the ID and the other can take its value from the fields **Name** or **Name_aux**. The logic is to take the value from Name_2 except if it is **NULL**, **empty (''**), or a **blank space**. I cannot make any change into the table.

T1 has an structure like this:

```
|ID|Name |Name_2|
|1 |T001 |      |
|2 |T001T|T001X |  
|3 |T002 |      |
```

I have used the `IIF` function but although I can use it from a script I cannot make it work in a query:

```
SELECT ID, IIF( (([Name_2] = '') OR ([Name_2] = ' ') OR ([Name_2] IS NULL)), 
[Name], [Name_2] ) AS NAME
FROM     dbo.T1
```

I have read in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818788/if-condition-in-view-in-sql-server) that it is not possible to use complex IF logic inside a view but since it is from some years ago, I want to ask again.

If there is no other solution, I can do a User Defined Function that receives two strings and returns one, but I want to avoid that.

Thank you

Comment: `COALESCE()` might be a better choice here. `COALESCE(Name_2, [Name])` If your data isn't clean and you do actually have Non-Null, but blank values that you have to test for then use `CASE` like `CASE WHEN trim([Name_2]) = '' OR [Name_2] IS NULL THEN [Name] ELSE [Name_2] END as [Name]`

Comment: This isn't "complicated IF logic", this could just be expressed as a CASE statement in the view.  Where you would have issues is if you started introducing aggregate IF logic, or something truly complex.  You statement would be CASE WHEN Name_2 = '' OR Name_2 = ' ' OR Name_2 IS NULL THEN Name ELSE Name_2 END AS NAME

Comment: `IIF` != `IF`. And the question you've linked to wouldn't have mentioned that distinction since `IIF` didn't exist until 2012.

Comment: Yes, with Case When logic I can fulfill my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Case` as next demo:-

```
declare @MyTable table (id int identity, name varchar(10), name_2 varchar(10))

insert into @MyTable values ('T001',NULL),('T001T','T001X'),('T002',' ')

select id, case
        when name_2 is null or name_2 = '' or name_2 = ' '
        then name
        else name_2
        end The_name
 from @MyTable
```

**Result:-**

```
1   T001
2   T001X
3   T002
```

Comment: @USeptim - as should you `IIF` version. It would have been good if your question had mentioned *why* it appeared not to work, e.g. error message(s).

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious reason why you cannot do that in a view -or a function for that matter. Some of our views ore quite hairy beats with many such conditional statements etc. The only requirement is that a derived column MUST be given an alias.